# How come $f(0) = 0$ in $\mathbb C/L$?

Tags: elliptic-curves

[image: How come $f(0) = 0$ in C/L?]

How come $f(0) = 0$ in $\mathbb C/L$? Does anyone know it? Your help will be appreciated. This is taken from the text "Rational Points on Elliptic Curves" by Tate and Silverman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that 
$$ f(z_1+ z_2) - f(z_1) - f(z_2) \in L \text{   for all $z_1$, $z_2$ close to $0$} $$
Now $0$ is (very) close to $0$, hence letting $z_1 = z_2 = 0$, we get: 
$$ f(0) - 2f(0) = -f(0) \in L \iff f(0) \in L $$
As $L$ mapsto $0$ in $\mathbb C/L$ we have $f(0) = 0$ in $\mathbb C/L$.